# android How can I check whether the certificate passed from server to device is a valid certificate?

Tags: android

Could anyone please help  to find  how  a valid Https  connection can be made from an android app.i  donot have a clear idea  of  How can I check whether the certificate passed from serveris a valid certificate? from my android app and establish a connection  with the server.which are the certificates supported by android

Answer (score 1):

It might be valid (as in not expired and with a signature that verifies), but not trusted by Android. Android will check both (trust and validity) when you connect to a HTTPS URL automatically, and you will get an exception if either of those checks fail.

Simply put, just try to connect to a HTTPS URL and see what happens.

'Supported' (i.e., trusted) issuer certificates vary by Android version, and since ICS (4.0), you can install your own.